# Alternative to detailinit event in Angular 2 Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

In the Angular 2 Kendo grid, I need to show additional info in each cell when the user opens the detail template.
In the Kendo Grid for jQuery I could use the detailinit (http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-detailInit) event to accomplish what I need, however, there is no such event in the Angular2 component.

```html
    <kendo-grid-column>
      <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem let-rowIndex="rowIndex">
          {{rowIndex}}
          <div *ngIf="????">
              Need to show this text when detail template is visible
              and hide when it's hidden
          </div>
      </template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <template kendoDetailTemplate let-dataItem>
      <section *ngIf="dataItem.Category">
        <header>{{dataItem.Category?.CategoryName}}</header>
        <article>{{dataItem.Category?.Description}}</article>
      </section>
    </template>
```

[Here is an example](http://plnkr.co/edit/nptoqpeqmgmj9kTygcZd?p=preview) what I need (please see the text in the cells).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @JoeC the question is not about a recommendation, it is about how to get a specific result with the grid component of Kendo UI for Angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, the Angular 2 grid does not provide information whether the detail template is expanded or not. Feel free to [suggest this as a feature request](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2).

---

**HACK**: To hack around this limitation, you can infer the expanded state from the HTML.

See [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7cg6bV?p=preview).

```ts
private icons(): any[] {
  const selector = ".k-master-row > .k-hierarchy-cell > .k-icon";
  const icons = this.element.nativeElement.querySelectorAll(selector);

  return Array.from(icons);
}

private saveStates(): void {
  this.states = this.icons().map(
    (icon) => icon.classList.contains("k-minus")
  );
}

private isExpanded(index): bool {
  return this.states[index] || false;
}
```

While this works, it is far from ideal, and goes against the Angular philosophy, and may break upon rendering changes.

Comment: Alex, thanks for your answer.
I have just created my own expand row feature implementation and submitted a feature request. Now I will wait for kendo release with detail template events implementation to refactor my code and use the native kendo feature.

Comment: The feature request [link](http://kendoui-feedback.telerik.com/forums/555517-kendo-ui-for-angular-2-feedback/suggestions/17602957-detail-row-events-in-grid)